# Laravel 5.3 Storage::put creates a directory with the file name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-filesystem

I'm using Laravel's file storage functionality to save a file:

```
public function dataPost(Request $request) {

    $fileInForm = 'doc';

    if ($request->hasFile($fileInForm)) {

        $file = $request->file($fileInForm);
        if ($file->isValid()) {

            // Filename is hashed filename + part of timestamp
            $hashedName = hash_file('md5', $file->path());
            $timestamp = microtime() * 1000000;

            $newFilename = $hashedName . $timestamp . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, $file);
        }
    }
}
```

This does save the file, but inside a directory named the same as the file, for example:

`storage/app/952d6c009.jpg/952d6c009.jpg`

or

`storage/app/234234234.jpg/234234234.jpg`

Is this expected? Is there any way to just store the file without a separate directory for each file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you need to provide the file contents in the second argument not file object, try this:

`Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, file_get_contents($file));`

Comment: Thank you, been searching on this issue for hours, it doesn't seem to be specified anywhere, and the Laravel docs only give a txt as example with a string as input.

Answer (score 15):

```
Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('', $file, $filenewname);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 12):

This happened because you specify the directory to store as filename. The `newFilename`, should be the directory name such as 'images'. Refer to this line

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, $file);
```

So you could change this to

```
Storage::disk('local')->putFile('images', $file);
```

Then you will get the path stored at `storage/app/images/234234234.jpg`

Comment: In this case at what point does the file get the new filename? Should I edit the `$file` object to update the filename? Something like `$file->originalName = $newFilename;` ?

Comment: you could do that or use @ABDEL-RHMAN

Answer (score 2):

$file is encoded.You have to unencode the file.

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, File::get($file));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very old question, today I had the same issue and I tried

`Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, file_get_contents($file));`

it was very useful but in my case I wanted to the file inside folders like `folder/folder/my_file.pdf`

this solution didn't help.

I also tried this
`Storage::put("folder/folder/my_file.pdf", $contents);`

didn't help too.

Found this magical function called [storeAs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name) and it made the trick
Here is one Example from my code.

```
$this->residence_paper->storeAs('folder/another_folder', $residence_paper.'.pdf');
```

Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**To create new folder or upload image to already created folder using laravel 8.83.27 Storage function**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$path     = 'uploads/employee/";
$filename = "testemp.pdf";                // For any file format
$image    = $request->image;              //base 64 format
Storage::disk('public')->put($path."/".$filename, base64_decode($image));
```