# Saving files locally with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm saving files locally in Laravel, however I'm having issues getting the right URL and accessing the files.

I've setup a symlink with Artisan:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

When saving, I add `public/` to the name, so the files are placed in the `/storage/app/public/` directory, which works.

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
    $files = array();

    foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $name = time() . str_random(5) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('public')->put($name, $file);
            $files[] = $name;
        }
    }

    if (count($files) > 0) {
        $response->assets = json_encode($files);
    }
}
```

The name is stored in the database

```
["1524042807kdvws.pdf"]
```

Then the assets are returned as part of a JSON object via my API for Vue

```
if (count($response->assets) > 0) {
    $assets = array();
    foreach (json_decode($response->assets, true) as $asset) {
        $assets[] = asset($asset);
    }
    $responses[$key]->assets = $assets;
}
```

Which returns `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1524042807kdvws.pdf` but that 404s. I've gotten myself a little confused I think, so any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found my answer on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002275/laravel-5-3-storageput-creates-a-directory-with-the-file-name)

I needed to wrap the `$file` in `file_get_contents()`;

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($name, $file);
```

and instead of `asset()` I used:

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($asset['file']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

As it shows there instead of

```
$name = 'public/' . time() . str_random(5) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

you can just have

```
$name = 'time() . str_random(5) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk("public")->put($name, $file); // assuming you have the public disk that comes by default
```

Then when you want to get an url, you can use the `asset` function

```
asset('storage/foo.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've gone through the docs. So i've updated my question to use `disk('public')` which is saving it in the correct place. I was already using `asset()` to retrieve the file but still 404ing

Comment: the file is stored in the correct path in the system? if it's under 'public' 
`asset('foo.txt');` should get it..

Comment: can you access any file by directly using the url in the browser ?

Comment: Yeah so it's in `/storage/app/public/1524042807kdvws.pdf` but like I say the `asset()` function returns `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1524042807kdvws.pdf`which just goes to my 404.

Comment: does `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/1524042807kdvws.pdf` return the file?

Comment: That shows a different 404 (Purple header) with `The requested resource /storage/1524042807kdvws.pdf was not found on this server.`

Comment: mucha gracias, el codigo me evita si existe dos archivos con el mismo nombre