# Laravel upload image in the Public Folder not in Storage Folder

Tags: laravel

I want the uploaded file to be located in the `public/uploads` folder directly like `public/uploads/my_file.jpeg`. Why is it that my code uploads it to `public/uploads/file_name/file.jpeg`?

here is the `filesystems.php`.

```
    'public_uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    ],
```

and here is the controller.

```
function upload_template(Request $request)
{


    $filee = $request->file('file_upload');
    $file_ext = $filee->extension();

    $file_name = $model->id . "." . $file_ext;

    Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put($file_name, $filee);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> This happened because you specify the directory to store as filename. The `file_name`, should be the directory name such as `images`.

Refer to this line :

```
Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put($file_name, $filee);
```

So you could change this to :

```
Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put('images', $filee);
// output : /images/234234234.jpg
```

You need to provide the file contents in the second argument not file object, try this :

```
Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put($file_name, file_get_contents($filee));
```

To specific the file name you can use `move()` method instead of `storage()` :

```
if($request->hasFile('file_upload'))
{
  $filee = $request->file_upload;
  $name = "my_file"; // name here
  $fileName = $name . $filee->getClientOriginalName();
  $filee->move('public_uploads',$fileName);
}
```

Comment: How to put specific file name?

Comment: in your `$file_name` variable `$file_name = "My Name";`

Comment: i think this `$file_name` becomes the folder. Its what happens in my code. How to specify the file name like `my_file.jpeg` instead of random `yyyte3542s.jpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is the best way you create a trait with 2 functions saveImage and 
//deleteImage

 public function saveImage($name,$folder){
$extention=$name->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename=time().'.'.$extention;
$path=public_path().'/'.$folder;
$name->move($path,$filename);
return $filename;
```

}

```
public function deleteImage($name,$folder){
$image_path=public_path().'/'.$folder.'/'.$name;
unlink($image_path);
```

}

```
  function upload_template(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file_upload;//$request->your input name
     $img=$this->saveImage($file,'uploads');

     //you can use $img for storing the image in database for example 
      User::create([
        'avatar'=>$img
       ])
 }
//don't forget to invoke your trait
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it [Laravel 5.3 Storage::put creates a directory with the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002275/laravel-5-3-storageput-creates-a-directory-with-the-file-name).

Need to provide the file contents in the second argument not file object.
Tt should be `Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put($file_name, file_get_contents($filee));`.