# Set name when uploading image file with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, minio

I'm working on uploading pictures to minio in laravel.

```
Storage::cloud()->put('image', $request->file, 'public');
```

Upload was successful, but it is saving random name.. now i want to assign name to it, what should i do.

Random name upload : **LD7fBO5seB8KMbYFS8wNafjK73hfA7lyUPAarGme.jpg**

Give me ideas.Thanks

Comment: Instead of ``image`` pass a file name that you want to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002275/laravel-5-3-storageput-creates-a-directory-with-the-file-name

Comment: This could help... $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName() . "somethingElse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ^^. Change `put` to `putFileAs`

```
    $data = $request->file;
    $originalName = pathinfo($data->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileName = $originalName . '-' . $data->guessExtension();
    Storage::cloud()->putFileAs('image', $request->file, $fileName, 'public');
```